# Why we have messed up values when we use enumerate to copy values from one array to another?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, enumerate

This is my code with comments saying the output of the print functions:

```
def rotLeft(a, d):
    rotArray = a
    arraySize = len(a)

    print(a)#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    for index, item in enumerate(a):
        print(index) # 0 1 2 3 4
        print(item) # 1 1 1 1 1
        rotArray[(index + 1) % arraySize] = item

    return rotArray
```

if I remove the last for instruction, we can retrieve the correct values. But if we maintan, somehow it does mess up with my original a array. Why this happen, and what is the good practice in this case?

Comment: `rotArray` and `a` are the same list. You didn't copy it, you just set another variable to the same object.

Comment: What is `d` for?

Comment: @schwobaseggl, it a variable to rotate the array, I will use when I fix this first part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rotArray` is referring to `a`, thus modifying it modifies `a`.

You can do this:

```
rotArray = a.copy()
```